# How to format objective-c block with clang-format?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang-format

I have the following code, for example:

```
[cardRegistrationVC setCancelBlock:^{
  [weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

When I apply clang-format on it, it turns into:

```
[cardRegistrationVC setCancelBlock:^{ [weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }];
```

As you can see, code inside the block appears on the same line. But I should be always on a new line.

How to set up clang-format correct? My following settings file:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
ColumnLimit: 120
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
PenaltyBreakString: 1000000
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I ended up writing blocks like this:

```
[cardRegistrationVC setCancelBlock:^{   
  [weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}];
```

Empty line at the end works ok.
Or you have to disable column limit:

```
#ColumnLimit: 120
```

Answer (score 9):

Just add this to the setting file(.clang-format).

```
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
```

Then the block will like this.

```
 [cardRegistrationVC setCancelBlock:^{
     [weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }];
```

Hope help you.

At the same time I would like add :

```
UseTab: Never
IndentWidth: 4
```